# Graph theory reference

Tags: graph-theory, reference-request

I am not sure whether I should post this here or at https://physics.stackexchange.com/ :if it is off-topic here fell free to move the post.

I am studying Loop Quantum Gravity, in particular Thiemann's book *Modern canonical quantum General Relativity*: there is a lot of graph theory I don't know, so I cannot understand all the concepts.

I need a book or a review that introduces me to the concepts of graphs, edges and all that. The reference must be geared for a physcist.

Comment: https://arxiv.org/abs/1302.4378, also https://physicstoday.scitation.org/doi/abs/10.1063/1.3035700?journalCode=pto and https://www.worldcat.org/title/graph-theory-and-theoretical-physics/oclc/513969 and https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/558476.Group_Theory_and_Physics

Comment: Any of those links useful to you?

Comment: @GerryMyerson yes the arXiv link is very useful

Comment: OK, I'll post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ernesto Estrada, [Graph and Network Theory in Physics](https://arxiv.org/abs/1302.4378): The abstract reads,

A book chapter consisting of some of the main areas of research in graph theory applied to physics. It includes graphs in condensed matter theory, such as the tight-binding and the Hubbard model. It follows the study of graph theory and statistical physics by means of the analysis of the Potts model. Then, we consider the use of graph polynomials in solving Feynman integrals, graphs and electrical networks, vibrational analysis in networked systems and random graphs. The second part deals with the study of complex networks and includes the models of "small-world", "scale-freeness", network motifs, centrality measures, the use of statistical mechanics for the analysis of networks and network communicability and the study of communities in networks. The chapter is finished by considering some dynamical models on networks, such as the consensus analysis, synchronization of coupled oscillators and epidemic models on networks.